# Recursion: why the top of the stack is repeating twice

Tags: objective-c, recursion

I don't understand why the top of the stack is repeating two times.

Here's my code:

```
void count(n){
    if (n>0) {
        printf("Count is %i \n",n);
        n=n-1;
        count(n);

    } else {
        printf("Count is %i. Finished. \n",n);

    }
        printf("The count here is %i \n",n); //recursion here
    }


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        count(5);

    }
        return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Count is 5
Count is 4
Count is 3 
Count is 2
Count is 1
Count is 0. Finished.
The count here is 0
The count here is 0
The count here is 1
The count here is 2
The count here is 3
The count here is 4
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

So, why are there two lines of output that say "The count here is 0" ?
Isn't the first line, the 'first' time through the recursion?

Comment: you have 2 print statements on fall through!

Comment: In future, use the breakpoint feature to find problems like this. Set a breakpoint on `count(5);` and descend in line by line watching as each line of code is executed.

Comment: I did use break points. I put one on `printf("The count here is %i \n",n); //recursion here`. But all I saw was it stay on that line and print "The count here is 0" twice.

Comment: That's not where you're recursing, though!  You're recursing around line 5 where you make the call to `count()` again.

Comment: Mitch, not sure what "fall through" is, but I think I only have one print statement after the If-Else condition. Right?

Comment: CodaFi, I understand I am calling `count` again, but after I drop out of the If-Else (after the "Finished" output), why is it keeping the value of n=0 twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about your code logically and I think you will see why that line is being printed twice. Consider the case when we reach this statement: `n=n-1;` and n is currently (before this is executed) equal to 1. Now n is 0 and you call `count(n)`, calling your function recursively as I think you might have been saying. Now your `count(0)` function call will go here:

```
else {
        printf("Count is %i. Finished. \n",n);

    }
```

because n is not greater than 0. This is where we have your output: `Count is 0. Finished.`
Then, your functions next statement is: `printf("The count here is %i \n",n); //recursion here`
This causes the first output of: `The count here is 0`.

Now consider what happens. Your `count(0)` call is done and returns to the function it was called from. In this case, consider where you called it from. You called it from the function which was called as `count(1)`, but now in that function, be causes of your `n=n-1;`, n is 0.

Following your code, after the if statement, your program will immediately proceed to: `printf("The count here is %i \n",n); //recursion here`

Because n is 0, it will output: `The count here is 0` again.

Comment: Ahh, brilliant! Thanks Iowa15. You're a life saver. Wasted hours on this before coming here.

Comment: Glad to help! Let me know if there is anything I should clarify. Also if you feel my answer best answered your question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to see the forest for the trees

Comment: @Iowa15, to demonstrate my understanding, here's a change I made that fixed the prob: `count (x)` Then I changed `{if (x>0) {
        printf("Count is %i \n",x);
        int n=x-1;
        count(n);` No sure if this formatted right here, but just wanted to say, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want:

```
n=n-1;
count(n);
```

rather than this?

```
count(n-1);
```

The former will modify the value of n printed in your later printf, whereas the latter only modifies it in the recursive call.

Comment: OK, I tried your code `count(n-1)` and now it prints the line "The count here is 0" only once. Don't really understand your explaination (yet), but I'll get it. At least now I have something to work with. Thanks!